# how to pass value from public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java, oop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);
    double low = data.nextDouble();
    Attacker type = new Attacker();
    type.setLow(low);
    Defender fight = new Defender();
    fight.result();
}
```

Defender class

```
private int ATKvalue;

public void result() {
    Attacker xxx = new Attacker();
    ATKvalue = xxx.ATKtype();
}
```

Attacker Class

```
public Attacker() {
    double low = 0 
}
public void setLow(double lowpercent) {
    low = lowpercent;
}
public int ATKtype() {
    System.out.println(low);
}
```

I simplified my code, but it is the same idea. When I run it, low is equal to 0 instead of the user input.  How can I change it equal to user input?

my code :

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Attacker {

    public double low, med, genPercent;
    private int lowtype, medtype, hightype;

    public Attacker() {
        low = 0;
        lowtype = 0;
        medtype = 1;
        hightype = 2;
    }

    public void setLow(double low) {
        this.low = low;
    }
    public double getLow(){
        return(low);
    }
    public void setMed(double med) {
        this.med = med;
    }


    public int ATKtype() {
        System.out.println(low);
        Random generator = new Random();
        genPercent = generator.nextDouble() * 100.0;
        System.out.println(genPercent);
        System.out.println(low);
        if ( genPercent <= low ) {
            System.out.println("low");
            return (lowtype);
        }
        else if ( genPercent <= med + low ) {
            System.out.println("med");
                return (medtype);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("high");
            return (hightype);
        }
    }       
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Defender {

    private int lowtype, medtype, hightype, DEFvalue, ATKvalue;
    private double genPercent;

    public Defender() {     
        lowtype = 0;
        medtype = 1;
        hightype = 2;
    }


    public int getDEFtype() {
        Random generator = new Random();
        genPercent = generator.nextDouble() ;
        if ( genPercent <= 1d/3d ) {
            return (lowtype);
        }
        else if ( genPercent <= 2d/3d ) {
            return (medtype);
        }
        else {
            return (hightype);
        }
    }

    public void result() {
        Manager ATK = new Manager();
        Defender DEF = new Defender();
        DEFvalue = DEF.getDEFtype();
        ATKvalue = ATK.getATKtype();
        System.out.println(DEFvalue);
        System.out.println(ATKvalue);
        if ( ATKvalue == DEFvalue ) {
            System.out.println("block");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("hit");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Manager {

    public int getATKtype() {
        Attacker genType = new Attacker();
        int attack = genType.ATKtype();
        return (attack);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Number of attack rounds: " );
        Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);
        int round = data.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter percentages for the number of attacks that will be "
                + "directed: low, medium, high. The total of the three percentages "
                + "must sum to 100%");
        System.out.print("Percentage of attacks that will be aimed low: ");
        double low = data.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Percentage of attacks that will be aimed at medium height: ");
        double med = data.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Percentage of attacks that will be aimed high: ");
        double high = data.nextDouble();
        if ( low + med + high != 100 ){
            System.out.println("The sum is not 100%. Equal probablilty will be used.");
            low = med = high = 100d/3d ;
        }

        Attacker type = new Attacker();
        type.setLow(low);
        type.setMed(med);
        System.out.print(type.getLow());
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < round ; i++) {
            Defender fight = new Defender(Attacker type);
            fight.result();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is being asked as if we can understand your goal, your problem, and your code not shown. Please don't assume this but rather add enough details for us to be able to fully understand your problem.

Comment: I just changed.. But it is very long, if thats ok.

Comment: Please **EXPLAIN** your code. Rather than just dumping your code and give some vague problem, please put a little effort into asking your question.

Comment: Muuuucccchhhhh better! +1

Comment: You have code that won't compile and you're leaving out key information. Such as methods. What is `getATKtype()`? I'll assume it's `ATKtype()` but even then, did you declare `low` as an instance variable? What is `type` in `type.setLow(low);`?

Comment: I just edited. Is it good?

Comment: The problem is that you create two separate instances of `Attacker` (the main problem, as there are many). It's better, still not good. Using `setLow` on one instance of `Attacker` won't affect the other one. Do not create an instance of `Attacker` in your `Defender` class. I'll write something up.

Comment: Now I've looked at your code. I can help you more now. However I have one question. Do you want the attack type and defense type to be randomly generated, or just the defense?

Comment: yes both are random, but user can determine the attack percentage

Comment: I'm going to use my own variable names to make things more clear.

Comment: @user3230613 Yes. I'm going to update my code in a few seconds. Let me know how it works.

Comment: @user3230613 No problem. I love object oriented programming (it's fun and interesting). Let me know how my answer works for you.

Comment: I can't have battle class . I can only have attacker , defender , manager class. :\ and I have to follow the outline, like at least 2 method per class..

Comment: @user3230613: This should be the last thing I have to say. First of all, that assignment is ridiculous then. It's bad teaching IMO. Anyways, you can still use ideas I've had. For example, instead of using the battle class to calculate who won, just simply do that right in the main "Manager" class. And you can create BS methods that don't do anything like `getMed()` even though you never need to use it. If my answer and this comment help you find your way, please accept the answer. Other than that, good luck and hopefully you get more logical assignment outlines in the future.

Comment: I can't use result in manager class either, it has to be in Defender class, but thank for helping me :)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Old answer.](http://pastie.org/8710687)

---

You are recreating instances of your `Attacker` class and the problem with that is the `low` value is associated with only that specific instance. So when you create a new one after the fact in `Defender`, you lose the value. I've also separated `Attacker` and `Defender` completely and created a `Battle` class that will take instances of `Attacker` and `Defender` and decide which one wins. That class is a face off of instances. This improves readability, logic, etc. It's a better design. Yours is sort of a mess with not much structure (no offense - just learning):

**Main class:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter attack low: ");

    double low = input.nextDouble();

    Attacker attacker = new Attacker();
    attacker.setLow(low);

    Defender defender = new Defender();

    Battle battle = new Battle(attacker, defender); 
    battle.result();
}
```

---

**Attacker class:**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Attacker {

    public double low = 0;

    public void setLow(double low) {
        this.low = low;
    }

    public double getATKtype() {

        double genPercent = new Random().nextDouble() * 100.0;

        System.out.println(low);
        if ( genPercent <= low ) {
            System.out.println("Attack: low");
            return 0; // low type
        }
        else if ( genPercent <= 1 + low ) { // genPercent <= medium + low
            System.out.println("Attack: medium");
                return 1; // medium type
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Attack: high");
            return 2; // high type
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Defender class:**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Defender {

    public double getDEFtype() {

        double genPercent = new Random().nextDouble();

        if ( genPercent <= 1d/3d ) {
            System.out.println("Defense: low");
            return 0; // low type
        }
        else if ( genPercent <= 2d/3d ) {
            System.out.println("Defense: medium");
            return 1; // medium type
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Defense: high");
            return 2; // high type
        }
    }
}
```

---

And finally, **Battle class:**

```
public class Battle {

    private double attackValue = 0;
    private double defenseValue = 0;

    public Battle (Attacker attacker, Defender defender) {
        attackValue = attacker.getATKtype();
        defenseValue = defender.getDEFtype();
    }

    public void result() {
        if (attackValue == defenseValue) {
            System.out.println("Block");
        } else if (attackValue > defenseValue) {
            System.out.println("Hit");
        } else { // attack is lower than defense
            // do what you need for that
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: my code is similar to yours. I just updated my real code, can you take a look?

Comment: @user3230613: Stop with your code for a moment. Take a breather and look at mine. *Understand* what I'm doing. I can tell you that you problem is still that you are still creating a new instance of your class Attacker `Attacker genType = new Attacker();` which you can't do. When you use `setLow` on your other instance, creating the new one will have no relation to the one you created in `main`. You need to have `Defender` take the instance of `Attacker` as a parameter in the constructor method. That way you can keep the instance consistent. **Start with my code, and elaborate from there.**

Comment: @user3230613: I don't want to dictate your program because it is yours. However, yours is hard for me to understand. What I suggest is to just start with my code. It's very simple and it works. Then, you want to add `medium` and `high` attacks right? You can do that. Do it the same as I did with `low` in my code because mine works. Just simply add things to mine. I've given you a baseline that works. I don't suggest changing the overall design of the classes because that's where you lose it. Just add methods and specific statements to what's already there.

Comment: ty, can you explain what is "Defender fight = new Defender(attacker);" why do you put attacker inside?

Comment: For terminology: `Attacker x = new Attacker();` <-- that is creating an instance of `Attacker` which is called `x`. Now, when you create the instance of `Attacker` in your `main` method, you use a method on it called `setLow`. That sets the `low` value in the class instance to be a value that you set it to. So, because we have to remember that value (and `Defender` needs to use that value), we pass the instance of `Attacker` to `Defender` in the constructor method like so: `public Defender(Attacker attack) {...}`. Doing that, we can maintain the value of `low`. Understand?

Comment: kind of.....I tried to add attacker ( in my case is "type"), but it is undefined. And my defender does not use that value, only attacker need to use, but it goes through many classes. result in defender class -> getatk in manager class -> atktype in attacker class( value use in here) , is it still possible to maintain the value?

Comment: I also posted my manager class. And thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

To pass a value into another class you will need to pass it as a parameter either of the other class's constructor or a setter method.

So if you give Attacker a `setLow(int low)` method, you can pass in the information.

```
public void setLow(int low) {
  this.low = low;
}
```

And then call the method when needed.

Comment: sorry, i forgot add that. I already have this method in my code, but it still 0

Comment: @user3230613: and? Are you calling it? Please try to provide all needed information to understand and answer your question from the get go. Having to pull information out in dribs and drabs can be very frustrating for you and for us.